# Title page and automated lists with deck.js and web-2.0 in slidify

Tags: slidify

I'm diving into slidify and have two problems that I cannot get solved. I've included a wee bit of example code so show where it goes wrong (example.Rmd file):

```
---
title       : My funny title 
subtitle    : 
author      : Claus 
job         : 
framework   : deck.js
theme       : web-2.0
transition  : fade
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : []            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {selfcontained, standalone, draft}
---

## Slide 2

Some text

* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
```

1. If I use the deck.js framework with the web-2.0 theme then I get no title page. I have been unable to figure out if that is because there is no title page for that framework or if I'm doing something wrong. A simple example code is provided below. If I change the framework to io2012 then the title page appears
2. I would like the unordered list on page two to be automated such that not all items appear at once. I read [here on this link](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify-old/blob/master/inst/examples/slides.html) that adding the build class to the ul tag should do the trick but I simply cannot get that to work.

Cheers,

Claus

Comment: Found a solution to 2: don't have to add the build class manually, but can make an incremental list by using `> *` instead of just `*`when defining the list items

Comment: The default `deck.js` template does not ship with a title slide. So you will have to add it yourself as the first slide. You can post a feature request on github.

Comment: Thanks. Will tinker with the title page instead of worrying about if my setup if missing something.